# Bokeh/Python: How to change data columns in CustomJS callback

Tags: python, callback, bokeh

Assume the source has 4 columns named `time_s`, `time_min`, `time_h`
    and `y`.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(...)
```

Then from those columns initially `time_s` and `y` are selected

```
p = figure(tools=tools, toolbar_location="above")
p.line(x='time_s', y='y', source=source)
```

In a CustomJS callback codeblock I would like to switch the x-column from `time_s` to maybe `time_min` and rerender the plot accordingly. I know how I can explore / access some of the data and objects in general by analysing them in the DevTools-console, but I cannot find the `x='time_s'` from the `p.line` object or how it can be accessed.

```
js = """
// Explore Objects in DevTools Console
console.log(data)
console.log(source)
console.log(plot) 

data = source.data
data['time_s'] = do something to column here ...

if (widget.value === 'xyz') {
    // Looking for something like:
    plot.line.x = data['time_min'] // not working
}

// After data change -> rerender
source.change.emit()

"""
cb = CustomJS(args=dict(src=source, plot=p, widget=mywidget), code=js)
mywidget.js_on_change('value', cb)
```

So how can this be done?

Comment: I know that I could just recalculate the column from 's' to 'min' and 'h' easily in a mathematical way, but this is a more general question, thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways I can imagine doing this. Assuming you can tolerate one column being duplicated in the data source, this is what I would suggest:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
foo = x**2
bar = np.sin(x)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=foo, foo=foo, bar=bar))

plot = figure(plot_height=350)
plot.line(x='x', y='y', source=source)

select = Select(value='foo', options=['foo', 'bar'])
select.js_on_change('value', CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, select=select), code="""
    // make a shallow copy of the current data dict
    const new_data = Object.assign({}, source.data)

    // update the y column in the new data dict from the appropriate other column
    new_data.y = source.data[select.value]

    // set the new data on source, BokehJS will pick this up automatically
    source.data = new_data
"""))

show(column(plot, select))
```

If duplicating the selected column in to the "y" column is not acceptable, then it *is* possible to update the glyph, to change what column it points at. That would look something like this:

```
r = p.line(x='x', y='foo' source=source)

cb = CustomJS(args=dict(r=r, select=select), code="""
    // tell the glyph which field of the source y should refer to
    r.glyph.y.field = select.value

    // manually trigger change event to re-render
    r.glyph.change.emit()
""")
```

Comment: Thank you @bigreddot, the second example was exactly what I was looking for.